# Printing out drop down list elements comes out in one big paragraph instead of separate lines

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Hey guys so I'm using selenium and I printed out all the elements in a drop-down list

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("url")
listofelements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'xpath')
for i in range(len(listofelements)):
    print(listofelements[i].get_attribute('textContent'))
```

It works, but not in the way I expected it to.
What happens is that it only goes through the loop once, yet all the elements inside are printed like one big paragraph, as if its just one html element, like this:

banana - orange - apple - grape

Instead of:

banana

orange

apple

grape

This is what the HTML code looks like:

```
  <select>
   <option value='1'>banana</option>
   <option value='2'>orange</option>
   <option value='3'>apple</option>
   <option value='4'>grape</option>
  </select>
```

There are multiple options yet the loop is only going through once and printing it all in one giant paragraph. Why is this happening and how can I make it so that it prints each option one by one on separate lines?

Comment: It looks like you're getting the outer `select` and not the options.  But it's impossible to tell without you providing the actual xpath you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you may be looking for something like:

```
listofelements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//option')
for elem in listofelements:
    print(elem.text)
```

Output (based on your sample html):

```
banana
orange
apple
grape
```